# Formal proof for $x^5= x$ in one's digit arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, modules

Although easy to prove by making table as below, but is it possible to have a formal proof of the fact that $x^5=x$ for all integers.

```
Unit digit (x)       modulus

---------------      ------     
   1                   1
   2                  32 mod 10 = 2
   3                 243 mod 10 = 3
   4                1024 mod 10 = 4
   5                 all powers end in 5
   6                 all powers end in 6
   7                16807 mod 10 = 7
   8                32768 mod 10 = 8
   9                59049 mod 10 = 9
```

Comment: When you say $x^5=x$ that sounds incorrect because $2^5=32\neq 2$.  Do you mean to say instead that $x^5\equiv x\pmod{10}$?  That follows from the chinese remainder theorem and fermat's little theorem noting that $x^5\equiv x\pmod{2}$ and $x^5\equiv x\pmod{5}$.

Comment: Alternately, an induction proof that $x^5-x$ is a multiple of $10$ is pretty easy. Especially if you note that it is always even.

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry, but as copied this question from a text, so cannot change the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any integer $x$, the number $x^5-x$ is always divisible by $2$ because $x^5$ has the same parity of $x$. Moreover, since  $x\equiv r\in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ modulo 5, then
\begin{align}x^5-x&=x(x^4-1)=x(x^2-1)(x^2+1)\equiv x(x^2-1)(x^2-4)\\&\equiv x(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)(x+2)\equiv x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)\equiv 0\pmod{5}
\end{align}
which means that it is always a multiple of $5$. Hence $x^5-x$ is always a multiple of $10$.

Comment: Why you have taken mod by 5 rather than by 10, is not clear to me; please elaborate.

Comment: $1\equiv -4$ modulo 5.

Comment: A number is divisible by $10$ iff it is divisible by $2$ and by $5$.

Comment: Nice way to show. Thanks for that. Btw, do your answer and the comment by @JMoravitz meet somewhere.

Comment: Yes they meet. My expansion of $x^5-x$ modulo $5$ is a particular case of Fermat's little theorem. $x^p-x=x(x-1)\dots (x-(p-1))$ modulo $p$ for any prime $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Any $x$ can be written as $10n+d$ where $d$ is a digit. Then by the binomial theorem, 
$$(10n+d)^5\equiv d^5\mod 10$$ and you are done with your table.

Comment: I feel that the need for 1..9 is still there for showing in tabular form. Your argument for doing away with table applies to integers with two or more digits. But, then it is obvious that the unit's digit is all that decides the outcome.

Comment: @jiten: that's exactly what I mean. The "cost" of the table for the digits is neglectible compared to the intellectual effort to find smarter methods. In fact, I am just using induction, with a base case made of the evaluation of ten numbers.